# Django session with angular.js

Tags: angularjs, django

I have set a view `Index(View)` to load a view for angular and it works fine. Angular communicates with Django and maintains session (Token base).

```
class Index(TemplateView):
    context = {}
    permanent = False  # docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def __init__(self):
        self.context = _.default_context()
        self.response = _.default_response()

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

        return _.render_view(request, self.template_name, self.context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        _.process_request(request)
        print request.POST
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print password
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_token,_ignore = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                self.response['status']=True
                self.response['statusCode']=200
                self.response['data'] = {'token':auth_token.key}
                self.response['user'] = {'email'                     : user.email,
                                     'first_name'                : user.first_name,
                                     'last_name'                 : user.last_name}
            else:
                self.response['status']=False
                self.response['statusCode']=203
                self.response['data']=[]
        else:
            self.response['status']=False
            self.response['statusCode']=404
            self.response['data']=[]
        return _.serialize_response(self.response)
```

Now anyone can access this page. I want to restrict user to access dashboard without login (in the case a user tries to hack by adding cookie or something).
If I create separate pages for login and angular:

- How can I handle different pages in one angular app?
- Do I have to create angular app intent?
- Something in Django?